# llvm problem in mesa3d build on linux RTDyldMemoryManager.h undefined reference to llvm::RTDyldMemoryManager

Tags: linux, gcc, llvm, mesa

I am on `slackware64 14.2` and I wanted to update to `mesa3d 21.2.1.so` I tried to so but it required `llvm >= 11`. I updated my llvm to version 11 configured with following command

```
CC=gcc CXX=g++ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/prog/llvm-11.0.1 -DLLVM_LIBDIR_SUFFIX=64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=ON -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=ON -DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=ON -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="host;AMDGPU;BPF" -DLLVM_BINUTILS_INCDIR=/usr/include -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS='clang;compiler-rt' -G 'Unix Makefiles' ../llvm && make install
```

after that I configured the mesa3d with following command

```
CC=/usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/gcc CXX=/usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/g++ meson .. --native-file ../nt.ini -Dplatforms=x11 && ninja
```

content of nt.ini

```
[binaries] 
llvm-config = path/to/llvm-config
```

It runs and build all but on linking there is following error

```
RTDyldMemoryManager.h:86: undefined reference to llvm::RTDyldMemoryManager::getSymbolAddressInProcess(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
```

I have tried compiling with `gcc-11.2.0`, `llvm-12` and I got the same result. Is this a problem with how I built llvm? Does somebody know what is wrong here?

Log of build :

```
CC=/usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/gcc CXX=/usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/g++ meson .. --native-file ../nt.ini -Dplatforms=x11 --wipe
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    The Meson build system
    Version: 0.56.0
    Source dir: /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1
    Build dir: /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1/bld
    Build type: native build
    Program python found: YES (/usr/bin/python)
    Project name: mesa
    Project version: 21.2.1
    Using 'CC' from environment with value: '/usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/gcc'
    C compiler for the host machine: /usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/gcc (gcc 10.3.0 "gcc (GCC) 10.3.0")
    C linker for the host machine: /usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/gcc ld.bfd 2.26.20160125
    Using 'CXX' from environment with value: '/usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/g++'
    C++ compiler for the host machine: /usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/g++ (gcc 10.3.0 "g++ (GCC) 10.3.0")
    C++ linker for the host machine: /usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/g++ ld.bfd 2.26.20160125
    Using 'CC' from environment with value: '/usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/gcc'
    Using 'CXX' from environment with value: '/usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/g++'
    Host machine cpu family: x86_64
    Host machine cpu: x86_64
    Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.21.1)
    Run-time dependency clang found: NO (tried cmake)
    Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency vdpau found: YES 1.1.1
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xvmc found: YES 1.0.9
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xv found: YES 1.0.10
    Run-time dependency libomxil-bellagio found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
    Run-time dependency libtizonia found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
    Run-time dependency libtizplatform found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
    Run-time dependency tizilheaders found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Dependency libva found: NO found 0.38.1 but need: '>= 1.1.0'
    Run-time dependency libva found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
    Program python3 found: YES (/usr/bin/python3)
    Fetching value of define "ETIME" : 62 
    Checking for function "bswap32" : YES 
    Checking for function "bswap64" : YES 
    Checking for function "clz" : YES 
    Checking for function "clzll" : YES 
    Checking for function "ctz" : YES 
    Checking for function "expect" : YES 
    Checking for function "ffs" : YES 
    Checking for function "ffsll" : YES 
    Checking for function "popcount" : YES 
    Checking for function "popcountll" : YES 
    Checking for function "unreachable" : YES 
    Checking for function "types_compatible_p" : YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute const: YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute flatten: YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute malloc: YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute pure: YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute unused: YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute warn_unused_result: YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute weak: YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute format: YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute packed: YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute returns_nonnull: YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute alias: YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute noreturn: YES 
    Compiler for C supports function attribute visibility:hidden: YES 
    Checking if "__uint128_t" compiles: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=implicit-function-declaration: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=missing-prototypes: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=return-type: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=empty-body: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=int-conversion: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wimplicit-fallthrough: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=thread-safety: NO 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-format-truncation: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-math-errno: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-trapping-math: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Qunused-arguments: NO 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-common: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=format: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Werror=return-type: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Werror=empty-body: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-non-virtual-dtor: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-format-truncation: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -fno-math-errno: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -fno-trapping-math: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Qunused-arguments: NO 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -flifetime-dse=1: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Werror=format: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-override-init: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-initializer-overrides: NO 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=pointer-arith: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Werror=pointer-arith: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Werror=gnu-empty-initializer: NO 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Werror=gnu-empty-initializer: NO 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmicrosoft-enum-value: NO 
    Checking if "GCC atomic builtins" compiles: YES 
    Checking if "GCC atomic builtins required -latomic" links: YES 
    Checking if "GCC 64bit atomics" with dependency not-found links: YES 
    Library ws2_32 found: NO
    Header <sys/sysmacros.h> has symbol "major" : YES 
    Header <sys/sysmacros.h> has symbol "minor" : YES 
    Header <sys/sysmacros.h> has symbol "makedev" : YES 
    Header <sys/mkdev.h> has symbol "major" : NO 
    Check usable header "sched.h" : YES 
    Checking for function "sched_getaffinity" : YES 
    Check usable header "xlocale.h" : YES 
    Check usable header "linux/futex.h" : YES 
    Check usable header "endian.h" : YES 
    Check usable header "dlfcn.h" : YES 
    Check usable header "execinfo.h" : YES 
    Check usable header "sys/shm.h" : YES 
    Check usable header "cet.h" : YES 
    Check usable header "pthread_np.h" : NO 
    Checking for function "strtof" : YES 
    Checking for function "mkostemp" : YES 
    Checking for function "timespec_get" : YES 
    Checking for function "memfd_create" : NO 
    Checking for function "random_r" : YES 
    Checking for function "flock" : YES 
    Checking for function "strtok_r" : YES 
    Checking for function "getrandom" : NO 
    Checking for function "qsort_r" : YES 
    Checking for function "qsort_s" : NO 
    Header <errno.h> has symbol "program_invocation_name" : YES 
    Checking for function "posix_memalign" : YES 
    Checking whether type "struct dirent" has member "d_type" : YES 
    Checking if "strtod has locale support" links: YES 
    Checking if "Bsymbolic" links: YES 
    Checking if "gc-sections" links: YES 
    Checking if "version-script" links: YES 
    Checking if "dynamic-list" links: YES 
    Compiler for C supports link arguments -Wl,--build-id=sha1: YES 
    Checking for function "dlopen" : NO 
    Library dl found: YES
    Checking for function "dladdr" with dependency -ldl: YES 
    Checking for function "dl_iterate_phdr" : YES 
    Checking for function "clock_gettime" : YES 
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency zlib found: YES 1.2.8
    Run-time dependency libzstd found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
    Run-time dependency threads found: YES
    Checking for function "pthread_setaffinity_np" with dependency threads: YES 
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency expat found: YES 2.1.0
    Library m found: YES
    Message: libdrm 2.4.107 needed because amdgpu has the highest requirement
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency libdrm_intel found: YES 2.4.107
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency libdrm_amdgpu found: YES 2.4.107
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency libdrm_radeon found: YES 2.4.107
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency libdrm_nouveau found: YES 2.4.107
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency libdrm found: YES 2.4.107
    WARNING: CMake: Dependency rt for LLVM target LLVMSupport was not found
    WARNING: CMake: Dependency dl for LLVM target LLVMSupport was not found
    WARNING: CMake: Dependency m for LLVM target LLVMSupport was not found
    WARNING: Ignoring LLVM CMake dependency because dynamic was requested
    llvm-config found: YES (/usr/local/prog/llvm-11.0.1/bin/llvm-config) 11.0.1
    Run-time dependency LLVM (modules: amdgpu, asmparser, bitreader, bitwriter, core, engine, executionengine, instcombine, ipo, mcdisassembler, mcjit, native, scalaropts, transformutils, coroutines) found: YES 11.0.1
    Run-time dependency libelf found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
    Library elf found: YES
    Run-time dependency valgrind found: NO (tried pkgconfig)
    Program bison found: YES (/usr/bin/bison)
    Program bison found: YES 3.0.4 (/usr/bin/bison)
    Program flex found: YES (/usr/bin/flex)
    Run-time dependency libunwind found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
    Run-time dependency OpenMP found: YES 4.5
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency x11 found: YES 1.6.3
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xext found: YES 1.3.3
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xfixes found: YES 5.0.2
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xcb-glx found: YES 1.11.1
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xcb-shm found: YES 1.11.1
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xcb found: YES 1.11.1
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency x11-xcb found: YES 1.6.3
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xcb-dri2 found: YES 1.11.1
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xcb-dri3 found: YES 1.11.1
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xcb-present found: YES 1.11.1
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xcb-sync found: YES 1.11.1
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xshmfence found: YES 1.2
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency glproto found: YES 1.4.17
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency dri2proto found: YES 2.8
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xxf86vm found: YES 1.1.4
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xcb-xfixes found: YES 1.11.1
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xcb-randr found: YES 1.11.1
    Using 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH' from environment with value: '/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
    Run-time dependency xrandr found: YES 1.5.0
    Library sensors found: YES
    Compiler for C supports link arguments -Wl,--gc-sections: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -ffunction-sections: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -fdata-sections: YES 
    Program nm found: YES (/usr/bin/nm)
    Program symbols-check.py found: YES (/usr/bin/env python /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1/bin/symbols-check.py)
    Program install_megadrivers.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1/bin/install_megadrivers.py)
    WARNING: Library target 'GLESv1_CM' has 'name_prefix' set. Compilers may not find it from its '-lGLESv1_CM' linker flag in the 'glesv1_cm.pc' pkg-config file.
    WARNING: Library target 'GLESv1_CM' has 'name_prefix' set. Compilers may not find it from its '-lGLESv1_CM' linker flag in the 'glesv1_cm-uninstalled.pc' pkg-config file.
    WARNING: Library target 'GLESv2' has 'name_prefix' set. Compilers may not find it from its '-lGLESv2' linker flag in the 'glesv2.pc' pkg-config file.
    WARNING: Library target 'GLESv2' has 'name_prefix' set. Compilers may not find it from its '-lGLESv2' linker flag in the 'glesv2-uninstalled.pc' pkg-config file.
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-unused-variable: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-unused-local-typedefs: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-maybe-uninitialized: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -fno-exceptions: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -fno-rtti: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wimplicit-fallthrough: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wshadow: YES 
    Compiler for C++ supports arguments -DNOMINMAX: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wimplicit-fallthrough: YES (cached)
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wshadow: YES 
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-arith: YES 
    Program /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1/bin/install_megadrivers.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1/bin/install_megadrivers.py)
    Checking for function "mincore" : YES 
    Program /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1/bin/install_megadrivers.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1/bin/install_megadrivers.py)
    Program /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1/bin/install_megadrivers.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1/bin/install_megadrivers.py)
    Program /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1/bin/install_megadrivers.py found: YES (/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1/bin/install_megadrivers.py)
    Configuring xa_tracker.h using configuration
    Message: Configuration summary:
     
     prefix: /usr/local
     libdir: lib64
     includedir: include
     
     OpenGL: yes (ES1: yes ES2: yes)
     OSMesa: no
     
     DRI platform: drm
     DRI drivers: i915 i965 r100 r200 nouveau
     DRI driver dir: /usr/local/lib64/dri
     
     GLX: DRI-based
     
     EGL: yes
     EGL drivers: builtin:egl_dri2 builtin:egl_dri3
     EGL/Vulkan/VL platforms: x11 surfaceless drm surfaceless drm
     GBM: yes
     GBM backends path: /usr/local/lib64/gbm
     
     Vulkan drivers: amd intel swrast
     Vulkan ICD dir: share/vulkan/icd.d
     
     llvm: yes
     llvm-version: 11.0.1
     
     Gallium drivers: r300 r600 radeonsi nouveau virgl svga swrast iris
     Gallium st: mesa xa xvmc vdpau
     HUD lmsensors: yes
     
     Shared-glapi: yes
     
     Perfetto: no
     Perfetto ds: auto
    
    Build targets in project: 228
    
    Found ninja-1.7.2 at /usr/bin/ninja
    bash-4.3$ ninja
    [2318/2364] Compiling C object src/gallium/frontends/xvmc/libxvmc_st.a.p/subpicture.c.o
    /usr/include/X11/extensions/XvMClib.h: In function 'XvMCCreateSubpicture':
    ../src/gallium/frontends/xvmc/subpicture.c:344:24: warning: 'palette_format' may be used 
    [2358/2364] Linking target src/gallium/targets/xa/libxatracker.so.2.5.0
    FAILED: src/gallium/targets/xa/libxatracker.so.2.5.0 
    /usr/local/prog/gcc-10.3.0/bin/g++ -o src/gallium/targets/xa/libxatracker.so.2.5.0 src/gallium/targets/xa/libxatracker.so.2.5.0.p/target.c.o -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -fPIC -Wl,--start-group -Wl,-soname,libxatracker.so.2 -Wl,--whole-archive src/gallium/frontends/xa/libxa_st.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive src/gallium/auxiliary/libgalliumvl_stub.a src/util/libmesa_util.a src/util/format/libmesa_format.a src/gallium/auxiliary/libgallium.a src/compiler/nir/libnir.a src/compiler/libcompiler.a src/gallium/auxiliary/pipe-loader/libpipe_loader_static.a src/loader/libloader.a src/util/libxmlconfig.a src/gallium/winsys/sw/null/libws_null.a src/gallium/winsys/sw/wrapper/libwsw.a src/gallium/winsys/sw/dri/libswdri.a src/gallium/winsys/sw/kms-dri/libswkmsdri.a src/gallium/winsys/nouveau/drm/libnouveauwinsys.a src/gallium/drivers/nouveau/libnouveau.a src/gallium/drivers/svga/libsvga.a src/gallium/winsys/svga/drm/libsvgadrm.a -Wl,--version-script /home/hsn/All/data/dev/bld/mesa3d/mesa-21.2.1/src/gallium/targets/xa/xa.sym -Wl,--gc-sections /usr/lib64/libz.so -pthread -lm -ldl /usr/lib64/libdrm.so -L/usr/local/prog/llvm-11.0.1/lib64 -lLLVM-11 -lsensors /usr/lib64/libexpat.so /usr/lib64/libdrm_nouveau.so -Wl,--end-group
    src/gallium/auxiliary/libgallium.a(gallivm_lp_bld_misc.cpp.o): In function `llvm::RTDyldMemoryManager::getSymbolAddress(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
    /usr/local/prog/llvm-11.0.1/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/RTDyldMemoryManager.h:86: undefined reference to `llvm::RTDyldMemoryManager::getSymbolAddressInProcess(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

update 1:
reinstalled slackware64-14.2 and again the same error

update 2:
i couldnt built mesa21.2.1 but i have successfully built mesa 20.3.4 with native gcc of slackware(5.4.0) with disabled gallium-va in configuration.

Comment: You can also ask at the official Slackware Forum https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/

Comment: ? Have you read the `mesa.SlackBuild` for mesa-21.2.1 →  www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.slackware.com/pub/slackware/slackware64-current/source/x/mesa/

Comment: thank you for reply. i locked it up and tried to build mesa with some additional option from mesa.SlackBuild but still no luck. additionally i rebuild llvm with similar option as slackware64-current and then mesa but the same linker error persisted.